# Getting a particular menu item from MainMenu

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, nsmenuitem

I have a nib (winA.xib) that contains a window. My app delegate contains an NSWindowController subclass called WinAController.

WinAController has a property (NSMenu *mainMenu) that I want to point to the MainMenu. I have set it after I instantiate WinAController with this code:

```
    WinAController = [[WinAController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"WinA"];
    WinAController.mainMenu = [NSApp mainMenu];
```

I have a menu item underneath the "Window" top-level menu item on MainMenu that invokes the [WinAController showWindow] method and displays WinA. I want to toggle the on/off state of this menu item depending on whether WinA is visible or not. WinAController also has another property (NSMenuItem *myMenuItem).

How can I get a reference to a sub menu of the "Window" top-level menu item. The title of sub menu item I want to get is "Command". I have tried this:

```
    if (mainMenu != nil) {
    myMenuItem = [mainMenu itemAtIndex:[mainMenu indexOfItemWithTitle:@"Command"]];
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks,

**Edit:** I have now placed WinAController in mainMenu.xib. I have set WinA's (in winA.xib) File's Owner to be of class WinAController but I can't figure out how to hook up WinAController's window IBOutlet to WinA as they are in different nibs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought I told you to put the Window Controllers in MainMenu.xib?

Oh well, nothing ventured, nothing gained. What you want to do, of course, is the following:

```
@interface MyApplicationDelegate : NSObject {
  IBOutlet NSMenuItem *winAMenuItem;
}

@property(assign) IBOutlet NSMenuItem *winAMenuItem;

@end
```

Then you can access this through `[[NSApp delegate] winAMenuItem];`

Comment: I'm very new to nib files and much of the work I've done to date has been creating things programmatically - I wasn't confident about creating a custom NSWindowController in IB. Perhaps I'll rethink now. I actually find IB more complex than Xcode at times!

Comment: As an aside, you hook up the window outlet in the window nib, and the menu item outlet in MainMenu.nib.

Answer (score 5):

You can store a reference to your menu item directly, possibly via IBOutlet in your main nib.

Or (better, IMO), you can implement `-validateMenuItem:` in `WinAController` and set the state there (that way, the state is only set when the user will actually see it, too):

```
- (BOOL)validateMenuItem:(NSMenuItem *)item {
    if ([item action] == @selector(showWindow:)]
        [item setState:[winA isVisible] ? NSOnState : NSOffState];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Won't the window controller only be in the responder chain (and so be able to validate the menu item) when the window is active? When the window is hidden, the window controller would not receive a validation message, so that method would not be able to reconfigure the menu item to reflect that state.

Comment: Not if the menu item’s target is the object in question, IIRC. If the item targets the first responder, then it’ll break, though, yeah. I should double-check…

Comment: Yeah, what I said only applies when the menu item is targeted at the First Responder. If it's targeted directly at the window controller, then yes, that will work.