# Enabling and Disabling Generic Window Menu Command

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, nsmenuitem

When you let the application open a window (`NSWindow`), a command after the name of that window appears under the `Window menu` as shown below where one of the commands points to the main application window and the other points to the opened window.

[image]

Provided that I know the name of the window the user is going to show, how do I enable and disable that command?  I suppose the following is not going to work.

```
- (void)closeGenericWindow {
    NSString *windowName = NSLocalizedString(@"controlListWindow",@"");
    NSMenuItem *windowMenuItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:windowName action:nil keyEquivalent:@""];
    [windowMenuItem setEnabled:NO];
}
```

I've run a search for '`[objective-c] [cocoa] disable window.`'  I don't find anything relevant except [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2869424/getting-a-particular-menu-item-from-mainmenu), which suggests that I create an `IBOutlet` in the header.  But the command itself doesn't exist until the user actually chooses to open the window in question.

Muchos thankos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably a couple of approaches to this:

- First, you can set the window's `excludedFromWindowsMenu` property to `YES` to simply exclude the window from the menu.
- Similarly, windows with no `title` do not appear in that menu.
- Finally, you can override `-canBecomeKeyWindow` to return `NO` and that should disable that menu, I think. You may need to override `-canBecomeMainWindow` instead or in addition.

Comment: Yes, the excludedFromWindowsMenu property works.  Muchos thankos.